# HuggingFace (Infomer) RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1536x23 and 22x32)

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying minimal example code of [Informer](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/informer) specified on HuggingFace website. However I am getting this error while running that:

Code:

```
from transformers import InformerConfig, InformerModel
from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download
import torch

# Initializing an Informer configuration with 12 time steps for prediction
configuration = InformerConfig(prediction_length=12)

# Randomly initializing a model (with random weights) from the configuration
model = InformerModel(configuration)

# Accessing the model configuration
configuration = model.config

file = hf_hub_download(
    repo_id="kashif/tourism-monthly-batch", filename="train-batch.pt", repo_type="dataset"
)
batch = torch.load(file)

model = InformerModel.from_pretrained("huggingface/informer-tourism-monthly")

# during training, one provides both past and future values
# as well as possible additional features
outputs = model(
    past_values=batch["past_values"],
    past_time_features=batch["past_time_features"],
    past_observed_mask=batch["past_observed_mask"],
    static_categorical_features=batch["static_categorical_features"],
    static_real_features=batch["static_real_features"],
    future_values=batch["future_values"],
    future_time_features=batch["future_time_features"],
)

last_hidden_state = outputs.last_hidden_state
```

Out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\data\test.py", line 25, in <module>
    outputs = model(
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\informer\modeling_informer.py", line 1711, in forward
    encoder_outputs = self.encoder(
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\informer\modeling_informer.py", line 1180, in forward
    hidden_states = self.value_embedding(inputs_embeds)
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\informer\modeling_informer.py", line 307, in forward
    return self.value_projection(x)
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 114, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1536x23 and 22x32)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the data or pretrained model's topology they provided in the tutorial cause some dimensionality error in the model's `InformalValueEmbedding` layers which consists of a `Linear` layer with input size 22 and output size 32. This layer in located and used in both `InformerEncoder` and `InformerDecoder` parts of the model:

`>> print(model)`

```
InformerModel(
  (scaler): InformerMeanScaler()
  (embedder): InformerFeatureEmbedder(
    (embedders): ModuleList(
      (0): Embedding(366, 2)
    )
  )
  (encoder): InformerEncoder(
    (value_embedding): InformerValueEmbedding(
      (value_projection): Linear(in_features=22, out_features=32, bias=False)
    )
    (embed_positions): InformerSinusoidalPositionalEmbedding(48, 32)
    (layers): ModuleList(
      (0-3): 4 x InformerEncoderLayer(
        (self_attn): InformerProbSparseAttention(
          (k_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
          (v_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
          (q_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
          (out_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
        )
        (self_attn_layer_norm): LayerNorm((32,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (activation_fn): GELUActivation()
        (fc1): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
        (fc2): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
        (final_layer_norm): LayerNorm((32,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
      )
    )
    (layernorm_embedding): LayerNorm((32,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
    (conv_layers): ModuleList(
      (0-2): 3 x InformerConvLayer(
        (downConv): Conv1d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3,), stride=(1,), padding=(1,), padding_mode=circular)
        (norm): BatchNorm1d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (activation): ELU(alpha=1.0)
        (maxPool): MaxPool1d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      )
      (3): None
    )
  )
  (decoder): InformerDecoder(
    (value_embedding): InformerValueEmbedding(
      (value_projection): Linear(in_features=22, out_features=32, bias=False)
    )
    (embed_positions): InformerSinusoidalPositionalEmbedding(48, 32)
    (layers): ModuleList(
      (0-3): 4 x InformerDecoderLayer(
        (self_attn): InformerProbSparseAttention(
          (k_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
          (v_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
          (q_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
          (out_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
        )
        (activation_fn): GELUActivation()
        (self_attn_layer_norm): LayerNorm((32,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (encoder_attn): InformerAttention(
          (k_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
          (v_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
          (q_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
          (out_proj): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
        )
        (encoder_attn_layer_norm): LayerNorm((32,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (fc1): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
        (fc2): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
        (final_layer_norm): LayerNorm((32,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
      )
    )
    (layernorm_embedding): LayerNorm((32,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  )
)
```

You can change the input dimension of these layers by

```
from torch import nn
model.decoder.value_embedding.value_projection = nn.Linear(23, 32, bias=False)
model.encoder.value_embedding.value_projection = nn.Linear(23, 32, bias=False)
```

but this will reset the pretrained weights in these layers. You want to fine-tune the model for some time to learn the weights there before making predictions.

Comment: I'll test with your code, thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: It works, thanks, FYI, this issue could also be solved by commented `static_real_features=batch["static_real_features"]`